# jquery can't get the value from an input element

Tags: jquery, select, text, input, case-sensitive

I am using jquery trying to retrieve the value of a text input but it is not working.  can anyone see what I am doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/rJNLr/

```
<input id="mytest2" value="123"/>
<button id="findRow">Find Row</button>

$("#findRow").click(function() {   
  var theVal = $("#myTest2").val();
  alert(theVal);
});
```

I apologize to everyone, but what I initially posted was just a typo when I was breaking the question down to simplify it.  I will have to repost again, only this time I'll put the unsimplified code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333135/jquery-cant-get-the-value-from-an-input-element-2).  I'll leave this question here though and add a tag for case-sensitive because I still think these were valuable solutions to others who may potentially have issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used wrong id `myTest2` which is not present use `mytest2`. Javascript is **case sensitive** so you need to take care.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/rJNLr/1/)**

```
$("#findRow").click(function() {   
  var theVal = $("#mytest2").val();
  alert(theVal);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `$("#myTest2")` to `$("#mytest2")`

Answer (score 6):

you have incorrectly mentioned the 'id' value of your field.

id values are CASE SENSITIVE in jQuery

hence, change

> myTest2 to 
>   mytest2

Answer (score 2):

Change `id="mytest2"` to `id="myTest2"`

Try this :

```
<input id="myTest2" value="123"/>
<button id="findRow">Find Row</button>

$("#findRow").click(function() {   
  var theVal = $("#myTest2").val();
  alert(theVal);
});
```

Which mean the id is case sensitiveness.